# Xcode 7.3 update error: "Use of unresolved identifier WLHttpMethodGet"

Tags: swift, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode7.3

I'm developing a native iOS swift application with Mobilefirst backend, and have integrated therefore the Mobilefirst API in the Xcode project.

Since the latest update to XCode 7.3 and swift 2.2 I'm getting the error: "**Use of unresolved identifier WLHttpMethodGet"** when calling the adapters though the WLHttpMethodGet method as in this code:

```
    let request = WLResourceRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "/adapters/SampleAdapter/adapterMethod"), method: WLHttpMethodGet)

    request.setQueryParameterValue("...", forName: "..")

    request.sendWithCompletionHandler { ( response: WLResponse,  error: NSError) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            ...
        }
        else if(response != nil){
            ...
        }
    }
```

Specifically in the line:

```
let request = WLResourceRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "/adapters/SampleAdapter/adapterMethod"), method: WLHttpMethodGet)
```

Is there any existing solution for this issue?

Comment: Please mention basic details such as your MobileFirst version and how did you create this native app - was the SDK added using CocoaPods or via a project in CLI/Studio?

Comment: Its IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.0.0.00-20151020-1831  and we created the native app via a project in CLI/Studio

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a defect in the product that is discovered by using the latest Swift release (v2.2).

You may want to open a PMR (support ticket) in order to track this while the development team is investigating.

A workaround could be to use a String "GET" in place of the constant.

Answer (score 0):

please check if you have opened project or workspace. In my case there are schemes with project, workspace and UATUI test cases as target. I was checking with workspace as we usually do for all the projects. But after swift 5.0 upgrade, I changed the scheme to project and the errors are gone and upgrade was successful.